# Real Analysis: Continuity example

Tags: real-analysis

f continuous and bounded on (0,1) that attains a maximum value on (0,1), but not a minimum value.

The function I have is f(x) = x(1-x)

I know this function attains maximum value at .5. My question is that whether this function function attains a minimum value and why?

Comment: " this function" twice... **which one** ??

Comment: The function $t \mapsto \sin (\pi t)$ attains a maximum on $(0,1)$ at $t= \frac{1}{2}$, but attains no minimum. Why? Because you can attain any value in $(0,1)$, but not $0$ itself.

Comment: Unless you know something more about the function, not much can be said. It could take an minimum value at whatever point in $(0,1)$ (apart from $.5$, of course). Or it could for example tend to $-\infty$ as $x$ tends to $0$, and thus not take a minimum at all. Or it could not have a limit as $x \to 0$ (think of $\frac{1}{x} \sin \frac{1}{x}$...

Comment: $f(x)=-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$ is another example.  (Max, but no min.)

Comment: The function I have is f(x) = x(1-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want such a function, just take a parabola opening downward with zeroes at $0$ and $1$, e.g., $f(x)=x(1-x)$. Otherwise, you’ll have to clarify the question.

Comment: The function I have is f(x) = x(1-x). This work for the condition right?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf: Yes, it does: it attains a maximum at $x=\frac12$, and since it’s strictly increasing on $\left(0,\frac12\right)$ and strictly decreasing on $\left(\frac12,1\right)$, it has no minimum on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

A function won't have a minimum value on an open interval $(a, b)$ if it is, roughly speaking, constantly decreasing as it gets really close to the endpoints of the interval (and does not reach a minimum somewhere in the middle of the interval).

Take the function $f(x) = -x^2$. On $(-1/2, 1/2)$ it has no minimum but reaches a maximum of $0$ at $x = 0$. If you want a function that works on $(0, 1)$, simply shift over $f$ to the right by $1/2$ a unit, to obtain your final function: $$-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2.$$

Comment: The function I have is f(x) = x(1-x). So this work for the condition right?

Comment: Yes, that works too.